# Creating media_bundle entities programatically

Tags: 8, entities, media

I am still trying to wrap my head around some of the D8 things.  Working with some media bundles like media_audio_bundle and need to write some migration scripts. I have spent couple of days now researching and trying everything but nothing seems to work.

Its like Drupal wall all over again.

This is the closest I came:

```
$audio = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
          ->getStorage('media_bundle')
          ->create(array(
            'type' => 'media', 
            'bundle' => 'audio', 
            'title' => 'Another Audio', 
            'field_audio_file' => 11
          ));
```

It seems to create some sort of media object but does not save it.

If somebody can help, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
use Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media;

$image_data = file_get_contents("URL OF FILE");
$file_image = file_save_data($image_data, 'public://FILENAME', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
$media_image = Media::create([
  'bundle' => 'image',(YOUR BUNDLE)
  'name' => "FILENAME",
  'field_image' => [
    'target_id' => $file_image->id(),
  ],
]);
$media_image->save();
```

Try this one, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

> You should invoke [save method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Asave/8.2.x) to save the entity to database.

```
$audio->save();
```

Comment: For some reason this would throw an error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but it seems to work.

```
$media =  Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media::create([
 'bundle'        => 'audio',
 'name'       => 'demo audio',
 'field_audio' => [
   [
      'target_id' => $file->id(),
   ]
 ],
]);
$media->save();
```